# Could not correctly configure the conda environment: env path error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, conda

**I Could not correctly configure the conda environment**

Before I run the command below, I did some `activate` `deactivate` operations, but **why the two output below of the command `conda info -e` are different?** I doubt that there are some configuration mixed in my OSX platform.

*Abnormal output:*

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/sonictl/anaconda
env_twint                /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/env_twint
py2env_conda             /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/py2env_conda
base                  *  /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/py3env_conda
$ conda config --show envs_dirs
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs
  - /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/py3env_conda/envs
  - /Users/sonictl/.conda/envs
```

But when I open a new terminal:

*Normal output:*

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /Users/sonictl/anaconda
env_twint                /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/env_twint
py2env_conda             /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/py2env_conda
py3env_conda             /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs/py3env_conda
$ conda config --show envs_dirs
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/sonictl/anaconda/envs
  - /Users/sonictl/.conda/envs
```

Thanks a lot!!

**Updated on Feb 17, 2020:**

I meet the strange conda environment configuration shown below:

[image]

I added lines below into the file `/Users/sonic/.conda/environments.txt`

```
base                     /Users/sonic/anaconda
env_twint                /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/env_twint
openNE                   /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/openNE
py2env_conda             /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/py2env_conda
py3env                   /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/py3env
```

But I still **unable to correctly manage the conda environments after multiple conda installed in multiple environments** :

Oringinally, my MacBook has a base environment which has installed the conda(v4.5.11). I used that conda(v4.5.11) to create a new environment named as `py3env`. Then, I installed a conda(v4.8.2) in the env of `py3env`.  See the below:

```
$ conda list conda
# packages in environment at /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/py3env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
conda                     4.8.2                    py36_0  
conda-package-handling    1.6.0            py36h1de35cc_0
```

Now, in `py3env`, if we run `conda info -e` command, we are not able to correctly display the environment list. Managing or switching the environment in `py3env` are also infeasible. You can see the original `base` environment in  `/Users/sonic/anaconda` is not visible.

```
$ conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
                         /Users/sonic/anaconda
env_twint                /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/env_twint
openNE                   /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/openNE
py2env_conda             /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/py2env_conda
base                  *  /Users/sonic/anaconda/envs/py3env
```

---

I tried to uninstall the conda(v4.8.2) from env `py3env` using Anaconda Navigator, but it prompt an `too low version` of conda in base. It asks me to firstly upgrade the conda(v4.5.11) before uninstall the conda(v4.8.2).

Comment: after I ran `source activate py3env_conda` everythion is normal. But `source activate py3env_conda` and `source activate base`, the problem happens.

Comment: pyCharm will activate the virtual env when open the terminal from its sidebar. The error exist when using terminal in pyCharm and activate the vir env `py3env_conda` by itself.

Comment: Does this still happen when using `conda activate` (the recommended way of activating)? `source activate` went out of practice some time ago. I can't reproduce the behavior.

Comment: @merv Thank you! I posted a picture showing this incorrect. You can check it.

Comment: Upgrade the conda(v4.5.11) in base environment (at `/Users/sonic/anaconda`) by:
`conda install -p "/Users/sonic/anaconda" "conda>=4.8"`
All is done.